# Create a type from properties in a class

Tags: typescript

Given the following class

```js
class A {
  name: string;
  age: number;

  doSomething() {}
  doSomethingElse() {}
}
```

I would like to get a type of only the properties of class `A`, like

```js
type PropertiesFromClass = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: @TobiasS. sadly no

Comment: The last answer in this post leads to the result that you want

Comment: If you don’t think this is a duplicate of the other question, please [edit] this question to clearly demonstrate the difference between them.